# node.js vs php на одном сервере?

Tags: php, node.js

Приветствую! 
У меня совсем нет понимания, что такое node.js.

**Задача:**
решили переходить **с angularJS на vueJS**

для vueJS мы хотим установить webpack

webpack требует nodeJS

Сайт работает на php.

Я правильно понимаю, что php и nodeJS на одном сервере не работают, и это какая-то ересь?
Для nodeJs нужен отдельный сервер?

Или можно совместить на одном сервере, и по определенному адресу будет работать nodeJS а по другому PHP?

Я совершенно ничего не знаю про nodeJS, кроме того что это javascript и работает на стороне сервера.
Поделитесь пожалуйста пониманием, хочу восполнить пробел в своих познаниях.

Comment: Может работать на разных портах

Comment: Маловато информации для ответа. Хотя бы покажите как реализовать и где почитать. Для дополнения: еще и в разных директориях и в разных виртуальных хостах (это все если очень хочется)